# Mapping Spring MongoDB AggregationResults ArrayList to List<POJO>

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I need to return a `List<AspectTemplate>` from MongoDB aggregation operation.

```
public class AspectTemplate {
  private ObjectId id;
  private String title;
  private List<String> options;
}
```

In Spring MongoDB repository I am mapping `AggregationResults` like this

```
ProjectionOperation projectOperation = Aggregation.project()
            .and("easpects").concatArrays("iaspects").as("allaspects").andExclude("_id");
AggregationResults<AspectTemplate> aspectTemplates = this.mongoOperations.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
            matchOperation,
            lookupOperation, projectOperation
    ), COLLECTION_NAME, AspectTemplate.class);

return aspectTemplates.getMappedResults();
```

The raw results are

[image]

But the `aspectTemplates.getMappedResults()` returns the following
[image]

[image]

How can I return `allaspects` ArrayList seen in raw results as `List<AspectTemplate`?

Comment: Your `ProjectionOperation` need to return `AspectTemplate` fields (`id, title, options`), but it returns `allaspects`

Comment: @Valijon can you throw in a small piece of code how can i convert the current projection to return fields instead.

Comment: Sure, but I need to know what hides behind `allaspects` field :D. If you run the aggregation in MongoDB CLI before projection, what JSON do you get? (post please in your question)

Comment: @Valijon added screnshot of `allaspects` element

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 2 extra operators into your pipeline and suggestion to modify your `Entity` class.

## Entity

```
@Document(collection = "COLLECTION_NAME")
public class AspectTemplate {
  @Id
  private ObjectId id;
  private String title;
  private List<String> options;
}
```

## Aggregation

```
ProjectionOperation projectOperation = Aggregation.project()
    .and("easpects").concatArrays("iaspects").as("allaspects")
    .andExclude("_id");
UnwindOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("allaspects");
ReplaceRootOperation replaceRoot = Aggregation.replaceRoot("allaspects");
AggregationResults<AspectTemplate> aspectTemplates = mongoOperations.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
            matchOperation,
            lookupOperation, projectOperation,
            unwind, replaceRoot
    ), mongoOperations.getCollectionName(AspectTemplate.class), AspectTemplate.class);

return aspectTemplates.getMappedResults();
```